# How to submit by by pressing enter button in addition to clicking Bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have the following HTML code for inputting prompts to a chatbot:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chat-input">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button id="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Enter</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the Javascript code that executes upon clicking the button:

```
$("#button").click(function(){

.......

}
```

However, this only submits upon clicking the button, not upon pressing the enter button.

I have tried the following modifictions to the above Javascript code. However, none of them succeed in submitting the prompt by using the Enter button.

```
$("#button").keyup(function(event){
.........
}
```

```
$("#button").on('click', function(event){
...........
}
```

Comment: Try adding your keyup listener to the document, not just the button. If you add it to the button, I think it would have to have the focus already.

Comment: This is a native behavior when you have your inputs within a `<form>`. Just put your inputs and button within a `<form>` and voila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen to a keypress press event to be able to handle the other case.

Click

```
$('#gpt-button').click(function() {
  call your handler function here;
});
```

Enter (keypress event for listening when the entry key is hit.)

```
$('#chat-input').keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) { // 13 is the key code for 'Enter'
    call your handler function;
  }
});
```

I hope this helps. Thanks.